# PySpark error getting year from date string by slicing

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need some help with adding a column with PySpark. I am trying to slice my date string just so I can get the year.

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```python
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame( [ ("12/12/1980",1,2) ], ("Date","Num", "#"))

df = df.withColumn("Year", df.Date[-4:])
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark doesn't support Python-slice slicing with negative indices. You could

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("Year", df.Date[F.length(df.Date)-3:F.length(df.Date)])
```

but it might be easier to just split

```
df.withColumn("Year", F.split(df.Date, "/")[2])
```

or parse (assuming day/month/year format):

```
df.withColumn("Year", F.year(F.to_date(df.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in functions from `pyspark.sql.functions` to parse into a date and then extract the year:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, year

>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("12/12/1980",1,2)], ("Date","Num", "#"))
>>> df2 = df.withColumn("Year", year(to_date(df.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")))
>>> df2.show()
+----------+---+---+----+
|      Date|Num|  #|Year|
+----------+---+---+----+
|12/12/1980|  1|  2|1980|
+----------+---+---+----+
```